# How to concatenate two xml files in python?

Tags: python

Using the Python module `import xml.etree.ElementTree` , how can I concatenate two files? Assuming each file is written to disk and NOT hard coded in. As an illustration of the Linux environment, cat is being used to print the contents of each of these files.

[<user/path>]$ cat file1.xml

```
<file>has_content</file>
```

[<user/path>]$ cat file2.xml

```
<root>more_content</root>
```

After each of the files has been opened and concatenated to the first

[<user/path>]$ cat new_file.xml

```
<new_root><file>has_content</file><root><more_content</root></new_root>
```

I would like to simply 'merge' these two files together but I have been struggling. All I have been really able to find is about appending to a child or adding a SubElement.

Comment: The target file from your sample is syntactically invalid. You can't have two elements at the root level.

Comment: You have to transform them - maybe add a containing tag so the overal XML is valid - noting there must only be one containing tag in an XML file. Notepad++ has an XML plugin so could try doing it manually and then check the XML syntax there, might be a good idea before you start coding. Test it out using your naive concenated "XML" above, will show it isn't valid.

Comment: so do you think this is the correct way then? <new_root><file>has_content</file><root>more_content</root></new_root>

Comment: That would technically work. Is it what you need?

Comment: yes, that is what I need. The files are both massive but they need to just be appended one after another. I'm new to xml so I believe making a new root would be suitable

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this and check whether your requirement is satisfied. I have used the module `xml.etree.ElementTree` for getting the XML data of files file1, file2 and then appended the contents to a new file with the root node being

```
<new_root>
...
</new_root>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data1 = ET.tostring(ET.parse('file1.xml').getroot()).decode("utf-8")
data2 = ET.tostring(ET.parse('file2.xml').getroot()).decode("utf-8")
f = open("new_file.xml", "a+")
f.write('<new_root>')
f.write(data1)
f.write(data2)
f.write('</new_root>')
f.close()
```